# Recursive Linq query - Person > Manager > Dept

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Say I have a dataset such as this:

```
PersonId  |   ManagerId  |  DepartmentId
========================================

1             null          1
2             1             1
3             1             2
4             2             1
```

and so on.

I am looking for a Linq query which:

> Given a **ManagerId** and a set of
>   **DepartmentIds** will give me all
>   relevant **PersonIds**. The query should
>   return **all PersonIds** under a manager,
>   all the way down the tree, not just
>   those immediately under that manager.

Here's what I've tried so far: http://pastebin.com/zF9dq6wj

Thanks!
Chris.

Comment: Sigh.  What have you tried, how did that not work, what research have you done to try to find the solution, etc.

Comment: Your tree has a static 3 levels?

Comment: Hi, no - theoretically it could have unlimited levels. Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with: `The query should return all PersonIds under a manager, all the way down the tree, not just those immediately under that manager` and how does that fit with the dataset you show as an example? Nevermind :p wasn't looking, understood now.

Comment: I think your missing the self referencing FK in your description

Comment: For Paul, because he asked so nicely: http://pastebin.com/zF9dq6wj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Linq, there's no automatic way to do this (that I've ever heard of) without multiple trips to the database. As such, it's really no different than any other recursive call structure and you can chose between recursive method calls, a while with a System.Collections.Queue (or Stack) object for ids, etc. If your backend database is SQL Server 2008 or higher, you can make use of it's recursive query capabilities, but you'll have to call a sproc to do it as Linq won't be able to make the translation itself.

Answer (score 1):

You cant do recursive queries in Linq2SQL or Linq2Entities. I would suggest writing a View with a CTE and add that to your DataContext file.